# Laravel 8 JS breaking when minified by Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, babeljs, production-environment, laravel-mix

I have a project I am working on that works fine with npm run dev/npm run watch.

When we moved it to production and ran npm run prod, we had a console error of;

`t is undefined`

This error did not show up on the login page, but after you redirected you could not get to any page without that error showing up.

The issue only shows up in the minified code, but "t is undefined" is very nondescript in 20000+ instances of t being in a minified file. Is there any way to track down where the error might be originating from?

Specs;
Laravel 8 - Jetstream - Inertia.js - Vue3

package.json

```
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.0",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.11",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "sugar": "^2.0.6"
    }
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .alias({
        '@': 'resources/js',
    });

mix.browserSync();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: Try generating a [sourcemap](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/api#sourcemapsgenerateforproduction-devtype-productiontype)